# Check whether full disk encryption is active?

Tags: encryption

Quick question. Is there a way to check if full disk encryption is active in elementary OS?

Eduard

Answer (score 1):

In terminal use `ls -A /home` command.

If there is *.ecryptfs* folder then it's encrypted. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can boot from a liveusb and attempt to mount your partitions.
I you are prompted for a passphrase then It's encrypted. Just to be sure it was done correctly. :)